# Why use trailing newlines instead of leading with printf?

Tags: c

I heard that you should avoid leading newlines when using `printf`. So that instead of `printf("\nHello World!")` you should use `printf("Hello World!\n")`

In this particular example above it does not make sense, since the output would be different, but consider this:

```
printf("Initializing");
init();
printf("\nProcessing");
process_data();
printf("\nExiting");
```

compared to:

```
printf("Initializing\n");
init();
printf("Processing\n");
process_data();
printf("Exiting");
```

I cannot see any benefit with trailing newlines, except that it looks better. Is there any other reason?

> EDIT:
>
> I'll address the close votes here and now. I don't think this belong to Stack overflow, because this question is mainly about design. I would also say that although it may be opinions to this matter, [Kilian Foth's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/381712/283695) and [cmaster's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/381724/283695) proves that there are indeed very objective benefits with one approach.

Comment: This question is on the border between "issues with code" (which is off-topic) and "conceptual software design" (which is on-topic). It may get closed, but don't take it too hard. I think adding concrete code examples was the right choice nevertheless.

Comment: The last line would merge with the command prompt on linux without a trailing newline.

Comment: If it "looks better" and it has no downside, that's a good enough reason to do it, IMO. Writing good code is no different to writing a good novel or a good technical paper - the devil is *always* in the detail.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: I believe that depends on your shell. `bash` will print the prompt immediately wherever the cursor may be, but `zsh` will put a mark there and start the prompt on the next line.

Comment: Do `init()` and `process_data()` print anything themselves? What would you expect the result to look like if they did?

Comment: @Bergi That scenario has already been answered below, but thanks.

Comment: Minor thing: If you're `printf`ing a constant string which always has a newline at the end, consider `puts`. Your compiler might optimize the calls into the same assembly, but it's better to be explicit about what you want to do.

Comment: Note that in Lisp [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) prints newline before printing the object. IOW, the "traditional Lisp output paradigm" conforms to your "leading newline idea". Not that this is exceptionally convenient...

Comment: `\n` is a line **terminator**, not a line **separator**. This is evidenced by the fact that text files, on UNIX, almost always end in `\n`.

Comment: Further to @Jonathon's comment, if a program's output doesn't end with a newline, the next shell prompt printed after it exits will be on the same line as the last line of output.  e.g. if I run `echo -n my_output`, then I'll see `my_outputpeter@volta:/tmp$ ` with the cursor at the end of that waiting for me to type the next command.  You should always end your program's output with a newline unless you have a very specific reason.

Comment: To put Peter Cordes's comment in other words, that last `printf("Exiting");` should be `printf("Exiting\n");`.

Comment: @JoL Yes, but with respect to the answers I will not change it now.

Comment: Of course, the question would lose its meaning. It was meant as a comment to further Peter's, not a suggestion to actually change the question.

Comment: @GrandmasterB It depends on the shell I think. If I'm not mistaken zsh adds an highlighted `%` character (for EOF) and a newline to the console if the EOF would be on the same light as the current prompt.

Comment: @Bakuriu Few programs are written *exclusively* for use within zsh.  Also, someone already brought that up.

Comment: It might be helpful for the case of a carriage return \r instead of a newline \n. With many shells, the \r will move the cursor to the beginning of the line, so you can overwrite the previous content of the line (useful for progress indicator which should not scroll the screen). A trailing \r will place the cursor over the first character in the line, possibly making less recognizable or causing "cosmetic issues". Note that an explicit flush (e.g. fflush(stdout);) is typically requited after each printf() when no trailing \n is present..

Comment: @JonathonReinhart In fact, the argument could be made that on UNIX, files that don't end with a newline aren't and can never be text files, but binary files that happen to strongly resemble text files.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

A fair amount of terminal I/O is *line-buffered*, so by ending a message with \n you can be certain that it will be displayed in a timely manner. With a leading \n the message may or may not be displayed at once. Often, this would mean that each step displays the progress message of the *previous* step, which causes no end of confusion and wasted time when you try to understand a program's behaviour.

Comment: This is particularly important when using printf for debugging a program that crashes.  Putting the newline at the end of a printf means that stdout to the console gets flushed at each printf.  (Note that when stdout is redirected to a file, the std libraries will usually do block buffering instead of line buffering, so that makes printf debugging a crash quite hard even with newline at the end.)

Comment: @ErikEidt Note that you should use `fprintf(STDERR, …)` instead, which is generally not buffered at all for diagnostic output.

Comment: @Deduplicator Writing diagnostic messages to the error stream has its downsides as well - many scripts assume a program has failed if something is written to the error stream.

Comment: @Voo: I would argue that any program that assumes writes to stderr indicate a failure is itself incorrect. The exit code of the process is what indicates whether or not it failed. If it was a failure, then the stderr output will explain *why*. If the process exited successfully (exit code zero) then stderr output should be considered informational output for a human user, with no particular machine-parseable semantic (it might contain human-readable warnings, for example), while stdout is the actual output of the program, possibly suitable for further processing.

Comment: @Erik Eidt: At least in my experience, "\n" doesn't always flush output.  To be certain, you need to follow your debugging printfs with a call to fflush (stdout).

Comment: @Daniel Great, now you just need a time machine to fix all those other programs that didn't follow your convention.

Comment: @Voo: What programs are you describing? I'm not aware of any widely-used software package that behaves like you describe. I do know that there are programs that do, but it's not like I just made up the convention I describe above: that's the way the vast majority of programs in a Unix or Unix-like environment work, and to my knowledge, the way the vast majority of programs always have. I certainly wouldn't advocate for any program to avoid writing to stderr simply because some scripts don't handle it well.

Comment: @Daniel Pryden: Something you're perhaps overlooking is that for debugging output, writing to stdout (and using fflush) plays nicely with gdb.  stderr doesn't, if memory serves.

Comment: @jamesqf: On some platforms, transmission of data to stdout may be unsequenced with respect to transmission to stderr.  If both streams get merged and delivered to the same destination (such as a terminal), the lack of sequencing can make a real mess of things.

Comment: Also these days we have time-travelling UBs, so a program could fail because of code that follows a printf() call without said call actually happening, regardless of buffering issues.

Answer (score 74):

On POSIX systems (basically any linux, BSD, whatever open-source based system you can find), a line is defined to be a string of characters that's terminated by a newline `\n`. This is the basic assumption all the standard command line tools build upon, including (but not limited to) `wc`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, and `vim`. This is also the reason why some editor (like `vim`) always add a `\n` at the end of a file, and why earlier standards of C required headers to end with a `\n` character.

Btw: Having `\n` terminated lines makes processing of text much easier: You know for sure that you've got a complete line when you've got that terminator. And you know for sure that you need to look at more characters if you didn't encounter that terminator yet.

Of course, this is on the input side of programs, but program output is very often used as program input again. So, your output should stick to the convention for the sake of allowing seamless input into other programs.

Comment: This is one of the oldest debates in software engineering: is it better to use newlines (or, in a programming language, another "end of statement" marker like a semicolon) as line *terminators* or line *separators*? Both approaches have their pros and cons. The Windows world has mostly settled on the idea that the newline sequence (which is typically CR LF there) is a line *separator*, and thus the last line in a file doesn't need to end with it. In the Unix world, though, a newline sequence (LF) is a line *terminator*, and many programs are built around this assumption.

Comment: POSIX even [defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) a line as _"A sequence of zero or more non-newline characters **plus a terminating newline** character."_

Comment: Given that as @pipe says, it's in the POSIX specification, we can probably call it _de jure_ as opposed to _de facto_ as the answer suggests?

Comment: @Baldrickk Right. I have updated my answer to be more affirmative, now.

Comment: C also makes this convention for source files: a non-empty source file that does not end with a newline produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @R.. same with C++03. But since C++11 this changed to "behavior as if the necessary newline character were appended when missing". In C11, still, this UB remains.

Answer (score 31):

In addition to what other have mentioned, I feel like there is a much simpler reason: it's the standard. Whenever anything prints to STDOUT, it almost always assumes that it is *already on* a new line, and thus doesn't need to start a new one. It also assumes the next line to be written will act the same way, so it helpfully ends by starting a new line.

If you output leading-newline lines interleaved with standard trailing-newline lines," it will end up looking like this:

```
Trailing-newline-line
Trailing-newline-line

Leading-newline-line
Leading-newline-line
Leading-newline-lineTrailing-newline-line
Trailing-newline-line

Leading-newline-lineTrailing-newline-line
Trailing-newline-line
Trailing-newline-line
```

...which is presumably not what you want.

If you use only leading newlines in your code and only run it in an IDE, it may turn out okay. As soon as you run it in a terminal or introduce other people's code that will write to STDOUT alongside your code, you'll see undesirable output like above.

Comment: Something similar happens with programs that are interrupted in an interactive shell - if a partial line is printed (missing its newline), then the shell gets confused about which column the cursor is on, making it hard to edit the next command line.  Unless you add a leading newline to your `$PS1`, which would then be an irritant following conventional programs.

Answer (score 18):

Since the highly up-voted answers have already given excellent technical reasons why trailing newlines should be preferred, I will approach it from another angle.

In my opinions, the followings make a program more readable:

1. a high signal-to-noise ratio (aka simple but not simpler)
2. important ideas come first

From the above points, we can argue that trailing newlines are better. Newlines are formatting "noise" when compared to the message, the message should stand out and thus should come first (syntax-highlighting can help too).

Comment: Yes, `"ok\n"` is much better than `"\nok"`...

Comment: @cmaster: Reminds me of having read about MacOS using Pascal-string APIs in C, which required prefixing all string literals with a magic escape code like `"\pFoobar"` .

Answer (score 16):

Using trailing newlines simplifies later modifications.

As a (very trivial) example based on the OP's code, suppose you need to produce some output *before* the "Initializing" message, and that output comes from a different logical part of the code, in a different source file.

When you run the first test and find "Initializing" is now appended to the end of a line of some other output, you have to search through the code to find where it got printed, and then hope changing "Initializing" to "\nInitializing" doesn't screw up the format of something else, in different circumstances.

Now consider how to are going to handle the fact that your new output is actually optional, so your change to "\nInitializing" sometimes produces an unwanted blank line at the start of the output ...

Do you set a global (*shock horror??!!!*) flag saying whether there was any preceding output and test it to print "Initializing" with an optional leading "\n", or do you output the "\n" along with your earlier output and leave future code readers wondering why this "Initializing" *doesn't* have a leading "\n" like all the other output messages do?

If you consistently output trailing newlines, at the point where you know you have reached the end of the line that needs to be terminated, you sidestep all those issues. Note, that might require a separate puts("\n") statement at the end of some logic that outputs a line piece by piece, but the point is you output the newline *at the earliest place in the code where you know you need to do it,* not somewhere else.

Comment: If every independent output item is supposed to appear on its own line, trailing new lines can work fine.  If multiple items should be consolidated when practical, however, things get more complicated.  If it's practical to feed all output through a common routine, an operation to insert a clear-to-end-of-line if the last character was a CR, nothing if the last character was a newline, and a newline if the last character was anything else, may be helpful if programs need to do something other than output a sequence of independent lines.

Answer (score 7):

> Why use trailing newlines instead of leading with printf?

**Closely match C spec.**

The C library defines a *line* as **ending** with a *new-line character* `'\n'`.

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined. C11  §7.21.2 2

Code that writes data as *lines* will then match that concept of the library.

```
printf("Initializing"); // Write part of a line
printf("\nProcessing"); // Finish prior line & write part of a line
printf("\nExiting");    // Finish prior line & write an implementation-defined last line

printf("Initializing\n");//Write a line 
printf("Processing\n");  //Write a line
printf("Exiting");       //Write an implementation-defined last line
```

Re: *last line requires a terminating new-line character*.  I'd recommend to always write a final `'\n'` on output and tolerate its absence on input.

---

**Spell checking**

My spell checker complains.  Perhaps your does too.

```
  v---------v Not a valid word
"\nProcessing"

 v--------v OK
"Processing\n");
```

Comment: I did once improve `ispell.el` to cope better with that. I admit it was more often `\t` that was the problem, and it could be avoided simply by breaking the string into multiple tokens, but it was just a side-effect of more general "ignore" work, to selectively skip non-text parts of HTML or MIME multipart bodies, and non-comment parts of code.  I did always mean to extend it to switching languages where there's appropriate metadata (e.g. `<p lang="de_AT">` or `Content-Language: gd`), but never did get a Round Tuit.  And the maintainer rejected my patch outright.  :-(

Comment: @TobySpeight Here's a [round toit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit).  Look forward to trying your re-improved `ispell.el`.

Answer (score 4):

Leading newlines can often make it easier to write the code when there are conditionals, for example,

```
printf("Initializing");
if (jobName != null)
    printf(": %s", jobName);
init();
printf("\nProcessing");
```

(But as has been noted elsewhere you may need to flush the output buffer before doing any steps that takes much CPU time.)

Hence a good case can be made for both ways of doing it, however personly I don't like printf() and would use a custom class to build up the output.

Comment: Could you explain why this version is easier to write than one with trailing newlines? In this example it is not apparent to me. Instead I could see problems arising with the next output being added to the same line as `"\nProcessing"`.

Comment: Like Raimund, I can also see problems arising from working like this. You need to consider surrounding prints when calling `printf`. What if you wanted to conditionalize the whole "Initializing" line? You'd have to include the "Procesing" line in that condition to know if you should prefix with a newline or not. If there's another print ahead and you need to conditionalize the "Processing" line, you would also need to include the next print in that condition to know if you should prefix with another newline, and so forth for each print.

Comment: I agree with the principle, but the example isn't a good one.  A more relevant example would be with code which is supposed to output some number of items per line.  If the output is supposed to start with a header that ends with a newline, and each line is supposed to start with a header, it may be easier to say, e.g. `if ((addr & 0x0F)==0) printf("\n%08X:", addr);` and unconditionally add a newline to the output at the end, than to use separate code for each line's header and the trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

Leading newlines don't work well with other library functions, notably `puts()` and `perror` in the Standard Library, but also any other library you're likely to use.

If you want to print a pre-written line (either a constant, or one already formatted - e.g. with `sprintf()`), then `puts()` is the natural (and efficient) choice.  However, there's no way for `puts()` to end the previous line and write an unterminated line - it always writes the line terminator.